# Changing values of JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I want to change the values of "moves" by adding different sums to all the values.

```
{
    "tile-type":"hex",
    "atlas":"hex-green",
    "moves":[61,73,87,103]
}
```

So as an example if we add 1, 2, 3, 4 to each value respectively, the final result must be:

```
"moves":[62,75,90,107]}
```

Comment: so reference it and update the values.....

Answer (score 1):

Simply make an iteration by [***Array.prototype.map()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the object property of `movie` and add by the respective value from another array.

```js
const data = {"tile-type":"hex", "atlas":"hex-green", "moves":[61,73,87,103]};

const respective_values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
data.moves = data.moves.map((i, k) => i + respective_values[k])
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a regular javascript object and you can do it like this:

```
const foo = {
 "tile-type": "hex",
 "atlas": "hex-green",
 "moves":[61,73,87,103]
}

foo.moves = foo.moves.map(el => el + 10)
```

if it was JSON, it would look like this:

```
const json = "{\"tile-type\":\"hex\",\"atlas\":\"hex-green\",\"moves\":[61,73,87,103]}"
const foo = JSON.parse(json)
foo.moves = foo.moves.map(el => el + 10)

// optionally, convert it back to JSON
const newJson = JSON.stringify(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a JSON table. JSON is a string that can parsed into an object. Once it's parsed, you can use it as any other.

```
var myJsonObject = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
myJsonObject.moves = myJsonObject.moves.map(i => i + 10)
```